# Airflow - Call DAG througgh API and pass arguments in most method

Tags: python, airflow

I have a usecase to call a python script within a DAG  airflow through AIRFLOW API. This python scripts will receive arguments through JSON. I can run python on shell and it retuns result as expecetd.

My API POST is as below -

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/DAG-3/dag_runs -d '{"conf":"{\"hostname\":\"<servername>\", \"username\":\"<username>\", \"password\":\"password\", \"command1\":\"hostname\" }"}'
```

My DAG is as below:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='DAG-3',
    default_args=default_args,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=10)
    )


#cmd_command = "python3.6 /root/test21.py '{\"hostname\": \"json_data(hostname)\", \"username\":\"json_data(username)\",  \"password\":\"json_data(password)\", \"command1\":\"json_data(command)\"}'"
cmd_command = "python3.6 /root/test21.py '{{ hostname }}' '{{ username }}' '{{ password }}' '{{ command1 }}'"


t = BashOperator(
     task_id = 'execute_script',
     bash_command = cmd_command,
     dag = dag)
```

With this i am seeing the arguments from API POST is not picked, am I doing it right way. When i hardcode the bales in `cmd_command` DAGS are executed, however I am not sure how to pass this as API through a POST

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conf needs to be accessed by `dag_run.conf`.

```py
cmd_command = "python3.6 /root/test21.py '{{ dag_run.conf.hostname }}' '{{ dag_run.conf.username }}' '{{ dag_run.conf.password }}' '{{ dag_run.conf.command1 }}'"


t = BashOperator(
     task_id = 'execute_script',
     bash_command = cmd_command,
     dag = dag)
```

Comment: how can i get the output of command in the JSON response rather than checking logs